# How to delete items and clear a form using javascript

Tags: javascript

I apologize for posting this question, I'm just learning JavaScript and have tried using the information from other posts but just cannot get my code to work. The object is to create an li tag and insert list items to this newly created tag, then assign an event handler to remove an item if the user clicks on it. 
I have the list populating and can remove an item if I hardcode it but cannot for the life of me figure out how to assign the value of the item being clicked on to the removeItem function. I am also trying to clear the list when an item is entered but keep getting the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'reset'".
If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.
thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> Add and delete items Objective </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
p {
font-style: italic;
}
li:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<script>
// your code here! 
var itemList = [];

window.onload = init;

function init() {   
var addButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");  
addButton.onclick = addItem;

//var itemList = document.getElementById("list");
var itemsList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
itemsList.onclick = removeItem;
}

function addItem() {
var newItem = document.getElementById("item").value;
var ul = document.getElementById("list");             
var li = document.createElement("li");

li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));
ul.appendChild(li);
itemList.push(newItem);

document.getElementById("item").reset();
}

function removeItem() {      
var editList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
//    var editList = document.getElementsById("list");
for (var i = 0; i < editList.length; i++) {
var item = editList[i];

if(editList.options[i].selected) {
editList.removeChild(editList.childNodes[i]);
}
}   
}  
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<label form="item">Add an item: </label>
<input id="item" type="text" size="20"><br>
<input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Add!">
</form>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
<p>
Click an item to remove it from the list.
</p>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the info, I will give it another try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not set the value of the item input to an empty string rather than using reset?

```
document.getElementById("item").value = "";
```

As for removing the list items...

```
for (var i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
    ul.children[i].addEventListener("click", removeItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can only reset forms, so you have to select the form and then reset will work. f.e. with:

  document.forms[0].reset()
- your code is adding the eventhandler to all existing li-Elements, if you create some new li-Elements later, you have to add the eventhandler to it manually. f.e. in your addItem-Function with:

  li.onclick = removeItem;

after pushing the new Item

- in your removeItem-Function you have access on the clicked Element via this, so you can remove only this Element with:

  this.remove()

Answer (score 0):

You could change your addItem() and removeItem() functions :

```
function addItem() {
    var newItem = document.getElementById("item").value;
    $('#list').append("<li id='" + newItem + "' onclick='removeItem(this)'>" + newItem + "</li>");
}

function removeItem(id) {
    $(id).remove();
}
```